# Prevent loading pages with .php file extension (only load without it)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a rewrite condition in my .htaccess file which removes the need for .php file extension

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php
```

so http://site.com/blog opens http://site.com/blog.php

but if old users type /blog.php it will also load the page

is there a way to prevent or redirect pages with .php or any other file extention to the one without it?

i mean if user entered /blog.php or /blog.asp it should either fail to load or redirect to /blog (without extention)

Comment: So you fetch an answer and then edit your question. This is normally not helpful, only showing that you didn't ask for what you wanted to learn about in the first place. ... .

Comment: @hakre i don't see whats your point? Cobra_Fast asked me what i have in my .htaccess file so i edited my post (because its not possible to post it in comment), thank you for being so helpful!

Comment: What I mean is that you have taken over from an answer of which you wrote that *it does not work*. So all you did was using code that obviously *does not work* and you put it into your .htaccess file even you know that *it does not work*. I can not see how that should turn out into a useful question. You are just saying that you put code into your .htaccess file that *does not work* and that *you know that it does not work* and *even* you put it in your .htaccess file. And then you ask and say *that it does not work*. Have you tried reading the manual?

Comment: @hakre well, in that answer the problem was the loop, so i was hoping for a solution for this loop (when no one had another answer)! any way i'm sure you're here to help, thanks any way for your note, but it would be more helpful if you help to solve the problem as well as your notes :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way to accomplish this would be to only rewrite if a `.php` by that name exists. Otherwise throw `404` for the original URL. The second set of rules would take care of removing the extension and avoiding the redirect loop.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(?:GET|POST)\ /.*\.php\ HTTP.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thank you, this one somehow works, but if user enters /blog.php he is redirected to /home/username/public_html/blog and there it shows a Not Found error, is it possible to remove the /home/username/public_html/ part? or is this a problem from my side? i only have your code in my .htaccess file

Comment: Assuming your .htaccess is in root dir, modify the options as in my update.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: The `Options` line smells like guessing. Please do not push too hard with configuration answers, if it doesn't work it's just you didn't won in the lottery. Don't trick the OP into a situation he even understands less. Better direct him where he can obtain technical support for his webserver configuration, Stackoverflow might just not tbe the right website for that.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal thanks Ravi, yes it is root dir, and this actually worked, thank you very much for helping

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: Can you explain why you FollowSymLinks and also why you disable MultiViews? How is that needed for your answer?

Comment: @hakre To be honest I copied the header from my own `htaccess`. I know just the `RewriteBase` directive was probably enough here but overriding the `Options` is harmless and prevents your `htaccess` from breaking if the global options were messed up.

Comment: @hakre But, I'm amazed it bothered you so much to give me a down-vote. Cheers, anyway.

Comment: Wow, changing Options is less than harmless at all. And as you write, you don't even think it's necessary, so double the trouble. I wonder how you can be that less-caring as the OP obviously is not sitting in the saddle easily.

Comment: @hakre Yes, in this case it is because both the settings are required for `.htaccess` rules to work. I just helped OP out of his problem so you calling me less-caring is a little uncalled for.

Comment: @hakre You have three answers below that you and I both know won't work at all. (One with an undeserved up-vote as well.) Yet you give and defend your down-vote to me. That says a lot about you.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal i don't care if there is an additional line, no one helped me out in this except you and i'm really thankful for this brother, as for hakre please at least help in questions and then do this, if you're caring and had a nice and working answer better than Ravi's why didn't you help me?

Comment: +1 for this very good answer. Some people forget that SO is all about question and answers not about throwing online manuals on users. Those online manuals we all know are not very friendly. There is absolutely nothing wrong in including `Options` line also, totally harmless. What is more important is getting the rules right and this answer does that spot on.

Comment: It's actually not the only superfluous directive that is in there, so, I'd say the -1 is well placed. I wonder if you really care so much, why you respond that elusive and you don't detail on the questions asked back. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it puts the page in a loop> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: @Ara Updated with full code. Add an `[L]` to your old rule. Order of rules shouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: thank you for the update i did exactly that, but still a loop, the url now looks like this and finally fails to load > /public_html/home/username/public_html/home/username/....

Comment: no sir, only your code above, i also edited my post above with it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

This would cause apache to send back a redirect to the browser which would update it's URL to the one stripped from the extension. But make sure to place this rule in front of the one the redirects to .php internally

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.([a-z0-9]+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks but got error in browser > This webpage has a redirect loop (i have added the L to my first rule)

Comment: This answer obviously can not work, if you understand some of the RewriteRule basics you can even see that without trying with your server and browser.